# “I have lent him to the LORD"

Tags: 1-samuel, samuel

1 Sam 1:27-28b (ESV):

> For this child I prayed, and the LORD has granted me **my petition** *(šəʾēlātî*) that **I made** (*šāʾaltî*) to him.  Therefore **I have lent him** (*hišʾiltîhû*) to the LORD. As long as he lives, **he is lent** (*šāʾûl*) to the LORD.”

The transliterated words are all from the same root: *šʾl*, normally "to ask"<sup>1</sup>, creating a word play. I'm trying to understand:

1. How do we arrive at "I have lent"<sup>2</sup> and "he is lent"<sup>3</sup>? Is there support elsewhere for these conjugations with this meaning?
2. Is "lent to the LORD" a known way to describe dedication to temple service like this?<sup>4</sup>

---

<sub>1.  See also v. 20, *šəʾiltîw* = *I have asked for him*.



2. *Hifil* perfect: ?*I have caused him to ask to the LORD*



3. *Qal* passive participle: ?*He is asked to the LORD*



4.  See also v. 11 where she appears to be making a Nazarite vow (Num. 6) on his behalf (cf. Judges 13 on the dedication of Samson, not using this word).</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commentators all note the significant place that the root *š.ʾ.l* has in the opening chapter of Samuel. Because of the punch-line ("he is *lent* (*šāʾûl*) to the LORD") in v. 28, many also are minded to think that it belongs, rather, to a now missing birth narrative of Saul. This remains contentious.

It is also the case that the forms that bother OP have bothered commentators for a long, long time. In the 11th C, Rashi saw the need of [providing a clear gloss](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15830#v=28&showrashi=true) for v. 28 in particular.

> **(1)** How do we arrive at "I have lent" and "he is lent"? Is there support elsewhere for these conjugations with this meaning?

A fine question. The fact that dictionaries like [Brown-Driver-Briggs](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/982/mode/1up) give "lend" as one of the definitions, doesn't explain the oddity of getting from a Qal meaning of "ask" to a different concept altogether.

The "normal" explanation goes something like this. We have, in v. 28, the *Hiphil* form of the verb (*hišʾiltîhû*), as OP rightly notes. There are only two occurrences of this otherwise common verb (>160x in the Qal) in the Hebrew Bible: this one, and [Exodus 12:36](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+12%3A36&version=NASB;WLC). Of those two, only this example in 1 Sam 1:28 *must* be *Hiphil* according to the consonantal text; some re-vocalize the Exodus text to get a Qal.

Given those two texts, though, the suggestion goes that the *Hiphil* means to "let a person ask", so idiomatically "grant a request", and so here, literally, as [S.R. Driver has it](https://archive.org/stream/notesonthehebrew00drivuoft#page/22/mode/1up), "let (one) ask him for YHWH" = "let him be asked for (lent him to) YHWH".

This doesn't seem very satisfactory. Others, then, suggest that the *Hiphil* carries the connotation of "dedicate". Noting the combination with the preposition *le-*, [David Tsumura explains](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iLKAlhLDkMwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA133#v=onepage&q&f=false) the sense of the *Hiphil* this way:

> A causes X to be requested *to* B = A entrusted X *to* B

The level of uncertainty about either of these explanations (both of which have their followers and detractors in the wider literature) can be seen in the entry for *HALOT* which has difficulty seeing that either of them have much to commend them (see the conclusion in `(c)` in the entry):

> 1S 1<sub>28</sub>: there are two possible interpretations: (a) traditionally to lend, loan, so e.g. Gesenius-Buhl *Handw.*; Zorell *Lexicon*; Stoebe *1. Sam.* 99; ZüBi; NRSV: I have lent him to the Lord; cf. MHeb. שָׁאַל hif., JArm. שְׁאַל af. to loan out; so also Nab. (Lidzbarsky *Handbuch* 371; Cantineau *Nabatéen* 2: 148a); (b) “I treat him as one who has been requested ליהוה from Yahweh”, i.e. I entrust him (or consecrate him) to Yahweh, so Westermann *Ges. St.* 2: 174<sup>13</sup>; cf. TOB: I hand him over to Yahweh, assign him to Yahweh; REB: I make him over to the Lord; (c) deciding between these two possible suggestions is not easy, for in the end neither interpretation is very far removed from the other; the evidence from the cognate languages perhaps gives precedence to the first of them (a).

Perhaps, as [Graeme Auld points out](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qbi7BwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA34#v=onepage), the language seemed as tortured to the first readers as it does to us today, and is simply the author making a bad pun, or using forced language in order to keep up the use of the key root, *š.ʾ.l*.

> **(2)** Is "lent to the LORD" a known way to describe dedication to temple service like this?

Not to me. This language of "lending" is so odd in any case, that I'm not sure it's worth searching. I would be interested to know if others might be aware of something here, though.